# Models and Entities in MVP

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, oop, mvp

I'm a beginner in MVP design pattern and In a MVP triad, I have

**Model** - `AdvanceInfo`

**View** - `AdvanceForm`

**Presenter** - `AdvancePresneter`

and **Entity class** `Advance` as follows.

```
 public class Advance
{
    public int AdvanceID { get; set; }
    public decimal AdvanceAmount { get; set; }
    public DateTime AdvanceEnteredDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime AdvanceProcessDate { get; set; }
}
```

So Should my model be as follows...

```
class AdvanceInfo 
{
    public int AdvanceID  { get { return Advance.AdvanceID; } }
    public decimal AdvanceAmount { get { return Advance.AdvanceAmount; } set { Advance.AdvanceAmount = value; } }
    public DateTime AdvanceEnteredDate  { get { return Advance.AdvanceEnteredDate; } set { Advance.AdvanceEnteredDate = value; } }

    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string NameWithInitials { get; set; }
    public string BankAccountName { get; set; }
    public string BankAccountNumber { get; set; }

    public Advance Advance = new Advance();
}
```

or else...

```
class AdvanceInfo 
{
    public int AdvanceID { get; set; }
    public decimal AdvanceAmount { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string NameWithInitials { get; set; }
    public string BankAccountName { get; set; }
    public string BankAccountNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime AdvanceEnteredDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime AdvanceProcessDate { get; set; }

}
```

Note: 
* I'm using entity class `Advance` as an aggregate class in `DeductionInfo` class as well.
* I'm not using any frameworks like EF. Only VS. (Since this is academic purpose project)

I hope my question is clear; actually what I want to know is how entity classes are used to build model? or else can we use Model classes alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second way is better. The Model should not be coupled with the Entity model. You would need to map each property of the Entity model to the Model (`AdvanceInfo`). This can be done manually with some code along the lines of

```
Advance entityModel = new Advance();

AdvanceInfo viewModel = new AdvanceInfo()
{
    AdvanceAmount = entityModel.AdvanceAmount,
    AdvanceEnteredDate = entityModel.AdvanceEnteredDate
    // etc.
};
```

Or you can use a framework like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started) to do the mappings for you.